# Multiple ansible conditionals no longer work with version 1.9

Tags: conditional-statements, ansible

I have the following task file in one of my roles:

```
- name: check for initalized fixtures
  stat: path={{ fixture_init_file }}
  register: fixture_init

- name: copy fixtures
  copy: src={{ fixture_file }} dest={{ fixture_dest }}
  when: fixture_init.stat.exists == False

- name: debug
  debug: var=fixture_init

- name: db2
  debug: var=database

- name: install fixtures (mysql)
  shell: bzcat {{ fixture_dest }} | mysql --user=root {{ database.name }}
  when: (fixture_init.stat.exists == False) and (database.type == "mysql")
  register: fixture_init_result

- name: install password file (pgsql)
  template: src=pgpass.j2 dest=/root/.pgpass mode=0600
  when: database.type == "postgres"

- name: fixtures role map (pgsql)
  template: src=gls-pgsql.j2 dest={{ fixture_pg_roles }} mode=0644
  when: fixture_init_file.exists == False and database.type == "postgres"

- name: install role map (pgsql)
  shell: psql -d {{ database.name }} < {{ fixture_pg_roles }}
  when: fixture_init_file.exists == False and database.type == "postgres"
  sudo_user: postgres

- name: install fixtures (pgsql)
  shell: bzcat {{ fixture_dest }} | pg_restore -Fc -d {{ database.name }}
  when: fixture_init_file.exists == False and database.type == "postgres"
  sudo_user: postgres
  register: fixture_init_result

- name: mark fixtured initalized
  file: path={{ fixture_init_file }} state=touch
  when: fixture_init_result|success
```

When I upgraded to Ansible 1.9.0.1, I now get the following error:

```
TASK: [database | install fixtures (pgsql)] *********************************** 
fatal: [database] => error while evaluating conditional: fixture_init_file.exists == False and database.type == "postgres"
```

Those two debug statements show that the variables are properly defined:

```
TASK: [database | debug] ****************************************************** 
ok: [database] => {
    "var": {
        "fixture_init": {
            "changed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "path=/opt/bigsense/fixtures-initalized", 
                "module_name": "stat"
            }, 
            "stat": {
                "exists": false
            }
        }
    }
}

TASK: [database | db2] ******************************************************** 
ok: [database] => {
    "var": {
        "database": {
            "ddl_password": "bigsense_ddl", 
            "ddl_username": "bigsense_ddl", 
            "name": "bigsense", 
            "password": "bigsense", 
            "type": "postgres", 
            "username": "bigsense"
        }
    }
}
```

Why do these conditionals no longer work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fixture_init_file.exists` needs to be `fixture_init_file.stat.exists` ;)